# Java Perlin Noise height map generation lacks desired randomness

Tags: java, random, terrain, perlin-noise

I am trying to generate a height map using Perlin Noise, but am having trouble with generating truly unique maps. That is, each one is a minor variation of all the others. Two examples are below:
[image: Map 1]
[image]

And here is my code (most was just copied and pasted from Ken Perlin's implementation, though adapted for 2D):

```
public class HeightMap {

    private ArrayList<Point> map = new ArrayList<>();
    private double elevationMax, elevationMin;

    private final int[] P = new int[512], PERMUTATION = { 151,160,137,91,90,15,
            131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
            190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
            88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
            77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
            102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
            135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
            5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
            223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
            129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
            251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
            49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
            138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
    };

    public HeightMap() {
        this.map = null;
        this.elevationMax = 0.0;
        this.elevationMin = 0.0;
    }

    public HeightMap(HeightMap map) {
        this.map = map.getPoints();
        this.elevationMax = map.getElevationMax();
        this.elevationMin = map.getElevationMin();
    }

    /**
     * Generates a Height Map that is, along an imaginary z-axis, centered around the median elevation, given the following parameters:
     * @param mapWidth the width [x] of the map
     * @param mapHeight the height [y] of the map
     * @param tileWidth the width [x] of each tile, or Point
     * @param tileHeight the height [y] of each tile, or Point
     * @param elevationMax the maximum elevation [z] of the map
     * @param elevationMin the minimum elevation [z] of the map
     */
    public HeightMap(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int tileWidth, int tileHeight, double elevationMax, double elevationMin) {
        this.elevationMax = elevationMax;
        this.elevationMin = elevationMin;

        for (int i=0; i < 256 ; i++) {
            P[256+i] = P[i] = PERMUTATION[i];
        }

        int numTilesX = mapWidth / tileWidth;
        int numTilesY = mapHeight / tileHeight;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int t = 0; t < numTilesX * numTilesY; t++) {
            double x = t % numTilesX;
            double y = (t - x) / numTilesX;
            r = new Random();
            x += r.nextDouble();
            y += r.nextDouble();

            this.map.add(new Point(x, y, lerp(noise(x, y, 13), (elevationMin + elevationMax) / 2, elevationMax), tileWidth, tileHeight));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ken Perlin's Improved Noise Java Implementation (https://mrl.cs.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/)
     * Adapted for 2D
     * @param x the x-coordinate on the map
     * @param y the y-coordinate on the map
     * @param stretch the factor by which adjacent points are smoothed
     * @return a value between -1.0 and 1.0 to represent the height of the terrain at (x, y)
     */
    private double noise(double x, double y, double stretch) {
        x /= stretch;
        y /= stretch;
        int X = (int)Math.floor(x) & 255, Y = (int)Math.floor(y) & 255;

        x -= Math.floor(x);
        y -= Math.floor(y);

        double u = fade(x),
               v = fade(y);

        int AA = P[P[X    ] + Y    ],
            AB = P[P[X    ] + Y + 1],
            BA = P[P[X + 1] + Y    ],
            BB = P[P[X + 1] + Y + 1];

        return lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(P[AA], x, y), grad(P[BA], x - 1, y)), lerp(u, grad(P[AB], x, y - 1), grad(P[BB], x - 1, y - 1)));
    }

    private double fade(double t) {
        return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
    }

    private double lerp(double t, double a, double b) {
        return a + t * (b - a);
    }

    //Riven's Optimization (http://riven8192.blogspot.com/2010/08/calculate-perlinnoise-twice-as-fast.html)
    private double grad(int hash, double x, double y) {
        switch(hash & 0xF)
        {
            case 0x0:
            case 0x8:
                return  x + y;
            case 0x1:
            case 0x9:
                return -x + y;
            case 0x2:
            case 0xA:
                return  x - y;
            case 0x3:
            case 0xB:
                return -x - y;
            case 0x4:
            case 0xC:
                return  y + x;
            case 0x5:
            case 0xD:
                return -y + x;
            case 0x6:
            case 0xE:
                return  y - x;
            case 0x7:
            case 0xF:
                return -y - x;
            default: return 0; // never happens
        }
    }
}
```

Is this problem inherent in Perlin Noise because the 'height' is calculated from nearly the same (x, y) coordinate each time? Is there a way to implement the noise function so that it doesn't depend on the (x, y) coordinate of each point but still looks like terrain? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: not too sure about this topic but what will happen if you change the starting point randomly each generation?

Comment: @CiY3 I now have it choose a random tile to start upon, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from a friend of mine, I resolved the problem. Because I was using the same PERMUTATION array each generation cycle, the noise calculation was using the same base values each time. To fix this, I made a method `permute()` that filled PERMUTATION with the numbers 0 to 255 in a random, non-repeating order. I changed the instantiation of PERMUTATION to just be a new int[].

```
private final int[] P = new int[512], PERMUTATION = new int[256];

...

public void permute() {
        for (int i = 0; i < PERMUTATION.length; i++) {
            PERMUTATION[i] = i;
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        int rIndex, rIndexVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < PERMUTATION.length; i++) {
            rIndex = r.nextInt(PERMUTATION.length);
            rIndexVal = PERMUTATION[rIndex];
            PERMUTATION[rIndex] = PERMUTATION[i];
            PERMUTATION[i] = rIndexVal;
        }
    }
```